# SQL Server Datetime NULL value

Tags: sql-server, datetime, null

I want to insert values into a SQL Server table, but every time I get

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ddod'" error.

```
[ddod] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

I'm not inserting NULL value, but `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000`, because no datetime was chosen.

Is `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000` the same as NULL?

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000` is not a valid `datetime` and would fail anyway. How are you inserting this?

Comment: What is the valid zero `datetime`, I've something like this `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. I'm using INSERT query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'0000-00-00 00:00:00.000'` is not a valid `datetime`

```
select CAST('0000-00-00 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
```

gives the following error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Do you have the following options off?

```
set arithabort off
set ansi_warnings off

select CAST('0000-00-00 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
```

In that case it gets cast to `NULL` instead.

Is there any reason you are not using `NULL` anyway to represent the absence of a value rather than a "magic" sentinel value?

Comment: @PeterO - The minimum `datetime` is `'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000'`