# convert 0000:00:00.00 datetime sql

Tags: sql, datetime

I have `varchar` column where the `datetime` is saved and i have some date times with the normal  form `00:00:00.00` which i can convert to date time and some others with the following format `0000:00:00.00` which i can't convert them. how can i solve this problem?  I tried to convert it but i get an error for those values.

> select  (DATEPART(HOUR, (SELECT CONVERT(datetime,time,121) FROM table
>   ) ) * 3600) +     (DATEPART(MINUTE, (SELECT CONVERT(datetime,time,121)
>   FROM table) ) * 60) +     (DATEPART(SECOND, (SELECT
>   CONVERT(datetime,time,121) FROM table )   )   ))

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: can you give an example of data you getting in the column or its just 0000:00:00.00 ?

Comment: Please see this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674101/sql-server-datetime-null-value


Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu i dont get any error. Just Null values.

Comment: @AshutoshArya the values in the columns are like 0000:01:37.61

Comment: Did You get the answer ? if not please give me an example where there is hour part too...

Comment: @AshutoshArya yes ! Thank you . i used Substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided and the assumption that `0000:00:00.00` = `HHHH:MM:SS:NN`

```
DECLARE @t table (
   blah varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @t (blah)
  VALUES ('0:00:00.00')
       , ('0000:00:00.00')
       , ('0000:01:37.61');


SELECT blah
     , hours
     , minutes
     , seconds
     , milliseconds
     , DateAdd(ms, milliseconds, DateAdd(ss, seconds, DateAdd(mi, minutes, DateAdd(hh, hours, 0))))
FROM   (
        SELECT blah
             , Cast(left_part As int) As hours
             , Cast(SubString(right_part, 1, 2) As int) As minutes
             , Cast(SubString(right_part, 4, 2) As int) As seconds
             , Cast(Left(SubString(right_part, 7, 3) + '000', 3) As int) As milliseconds -- padded to 3 characters (trailing zeroes)
        FROM   (
                SELECT blah
                     , SubString(blah, 0, CharIndex(':', blah)) As left_part
                     , SubString(blah, CharIndex(':', blah) + 1, 20) As right_part -- FYI 20 = length of varchar field
                FROM   (
                        SELECT blah
                             , CharIndex(':', blah) + 1 As colon
                        FROM   @t
                       ) As find_the_first_colon
               ) As split_the_string_by_first_colon
       ) As work_out_component_parts;
```